# how to remove "Error inflating class fragment "

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I have an error saying "Error inflating class fragment". I saw different solutions like one is saying to extend fragment activity but this is not fragment this is an activity so are there any other solutions?
Following is my main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    addFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance())
    binding.navView.show(0)

    binding.navView.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(1, R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))
    binding.navView.add(MeowBottomNavigation.Model(2, R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp))

    binding.navView.setOnClickMenuListener {
        when(it.id){
            0->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance())
            }
            1->{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                replaceFragment(NotificationFragment.newInstance())
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransition = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransition.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, fragment).addToBackStack(Fragment::class.java.simpleName).commit()
}
private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransition = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransition.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, fragment).addToBackStack(Fragment::class.java.simpleName).commit()
}
```

}

Comment: post full error stacktrace and code of related fragment (java/kotlin and layout XML)

Comment: I changed fragment to frame layout so now error is gone

Comment: @Dua add your solution as an answer and mark it as the correct solution if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changes frgment to frameLayout and error is gone now